# How to get boolean value from JSON?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Suppose this is a value in a JSON I want to assign to a BOOL variable:

```
"retweeted": false
```

Here is how I parse JSON data:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *timeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

Now, I have a bool property defined as:

```
BOOL *retweeted;
```

Inside my class. When I do this while parsing the JSON:

```
tweet.retweeted = [[[timeline objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"retweeted"] boolValue];
```

I get this error:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: boolean should be defined as BOOL retweeted;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
BOOL *retweeted;
```

this is wrong, booleans are scalars, not Objective-C objects, so they don't need to be declared as pointers. Use

```
BOOL retweeted;
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. The warning has disappeared now. But when I do NSLog(@"%@", tweet.retweeted) it is now always null, it should be either YES or NO.

Comment: @Richard Knop have you tried with NSLog(@"%@",self.retweeted?@"YES":@"NO); ?

Comment: Yes, and you're lucky with it! Because YES = (BOOL)1 and NO = (BOOL)0, but NSLog looks for an object when encountering %@, and if it's 0 (=nil, null, NULL etc.) then prints `(null)`. If it was no-null, i. e. YES, then it would have tried to send [(BOOL)1 description] and that would have crashed. You'd better learn Objective-C before doing instane stuff.

Comment: I have used several times without problems, but your point is still good to know, thanks for your clarification.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 16):

My preferred way of doing it is:

`BOOL success = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"success"] boolValue]`

Clean, succinct and inline.

Comment: best answer so far

Answer (score 8):

After serialization with `NSJSONSerialization` the boolean is stored as an `NSNumber`. If you look at the type it actually stores is is a `__NSCFBoolean` but that does not matter. `NSNumber` is an abstract class that does not exist. The system stores the value with a concrete class.

So

`NSNumber* boolean = [serializedDictionary valueForKey:@"boolValue"];`

this returns a `@0` for `NO` and `@1` for `YES`. You can use is as a booleanValue by doing:

```
if(boolean.boolValue){
  // ...
}
```

Comment: "NSNumber is an abstract class that does not exist." - huh what? It **does** exist...

Comment: I read that NSNumber is kind of a wrapper class to make int and double values behave like objects. It does exist but how it stores the data depends on how you initialize it. When you look at the debugger you can see different types depending on how you initialize the object.